# DC signal to Integrated signal for analog filter circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, integrated-circuit, ac-dc

I'm new to analog electronics, and I am stuck on one issue. Let's say I have an input signal, like blue one:

[image: It's an AC input signal]

To get a DC form I can rectify it (got a grip on it.)  What I need is a smooth (regulated) signal without spikes like the red one:

[image: my precious]

Saturation is optional :)

To get this signal I need to use an  integrated circuit with op-amp and NF, like this:

[image: s]

How do I pick values for each component?

- R39/R40=gain
- R40*C37-integral time (*not sure*)

What excactly are they responsible for?  Can you advise where to dig for info?

Comment: Are you sure you need a low-pass filter or integrator? The blue signal seems to be approximately balanced so you won't see much variation at the output.
You may want to use a rectifying circuit instead.

Comment: Well, if I zoom in the X-scale, it won't be balanced at all, especially for my MC, unfortunately :(

Comment: Well, the reason I'm asking is because this circuit will do both: rectifying + low-pass filtering: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Electronic/ietron/rect3.gif
You can tune how fast it goes down with R*C.

Answer (score 2):

Just so we are clear...  you will need a rectifier, otherwise an integrator will yield the average of the signal and you will get zero. Use a precision full wave rectifier.

[image]
Source: https://circuitdigest.com/electronic-circuits/half-wave-and-full-wave-precision-rectifier-circuit-using-op-amp

The signal will then look like this:

[image]

After the signal you can then average it with an filter. The integrating filter you have above will average with a time constant, imagine a square wave, if you run the square wave through the integrator, you'll get something like this. With a more 'rounded' signal you'll get something that looks like you want.

[image]

If it's too noisy, you may have to try a higher order filter with two poles, or a different averaging filter. You can try filtering the signal with the time constant in octave or matlab to simulate it.

Comment: There is a full-wave version with only [one opamp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7BMW.png), but I forgot where I saw it (ADI? TI? ...?). It's finicky about matching resistors, though (here a Monte Carlo for 10% `R2`). Still, for this case it doesn't seem crucial and the other opamp can be saved for a 2nd order Gaussian/Bessel.

Comment: Also a rail to rail amplifier with good specs is recommended to avoid signal distortion

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, this is an active low-pass filter.

The parallel feedback RC pair (R39, C37) sets the frequency response
( 3dB cutoff freq = 1/(2*PI*R39*C37) in Hertz )

and -(R39/R40) is the low frequency gain

Comment: You mean even if I have rectified AC signal (which is **already** DC, but jumping), I stil have to think that it's a low-pass filter, but not the integrator?

Comment: Well, you don't really have a pure integrator by virtue of the feedback resistor R39.

Comment: With an integrator (no discharge resistor R39), the red output line would look like ramps instead of rectangles, and would decay *very* slowly on the fact the capacitor is only loosing charge through leakage